# I am not able to render the editText properly

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am not able to render EditText properly it going outside the screen
but in Graphical Layout tab in eclipse it is showing properly.
Please help I am new to android. I have written the sample code for 1st row

[image: Runtime image, this what I am getting when I run the android application]

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://*****.*****.***/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#FFFFFF" >

<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" 
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp">

    <TableRow>
       <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="29dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
    android:text="Counter Id"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textColor="#000000" />

       <EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
    android:ems="10" />

    </TableRow>
     </TableLayout>
```

Comment: If this the layout you are planing to create, just go with RelativeLayout.  TableLayout creates lot of issue while drawing.

Comment: In your tablelayout try to put this in see... android:layout_width="match_parent" android:stretchColumns="1" android:shrinkColumns="1"

Comment: give some right margin to your parent layout `RelativLayout`

Comment: thanks nicholas, android:shrinkColumns="1" worked

Answer (score 1):

Use Linear Layout with weight sum.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html

Or
Use Different Layouts for different Screen Size.
for Eg: LDPI, MDPI, HDPI, XHDPI, XXHDPI ect.